# How do I set the color of slices of a pie chart according to text?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, pie-chart

I have a data representing the health of projects such as green, red, yellow, and none.

The problem is that color does not really match the texts. it matches when there are green, red, yellow exists in the data set. However, other cases, they don't match the text such as for red, it gets colored with yellow.

is there any way that I can fix the problem?

I appreciate for helps!

```
output$PieHealth <- renderPlotly({

Projects <- Projects[Projects$VP %in% c(input$checkbox),]

PieData2 <- Projects[,c(1,4)]
PieData2$ID <- 1
PD2 <- aggregate(cbind(PieData2$ID)~HealthName, data = PieData2, FUN=sum)
#PD2 <- PD2[-2,] #Delete 'None' Value

plot_ly(PD2, labels = ~PD2$HealthName, values = ~PD2$V1, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'percent',
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste(PD2$HealthName),
        marker = list(colors = c('#229954', '#ffc107','#d32f2f'),
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1))) %>%
  layout(title = "Project Health",
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: use a bar chart :P (seriously, humans are much better at perceiving relative length than relative area.)

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of how your data look like?